# How to show close price on plotshape function in pine script version 5?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have this code in pine script but it says `Error at 41:59 Could not find function or function reference 'str'` How can I fix it?

```
plotshape(buyCondition, title="Buy Signal", text="buy " + str(close), location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` argument of `plotshape()` is of type `const string`.

> ***text (const string)*** Text to display with the shape. You can use
> multiline text, to separate lines use '\n' escape sequence. Example:
> 'line one\nline two'.

This means that its value must be known at compile time. So, you cannot use dynamic strings with it.

Instead, you can use `label.new()`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

sma_val = ta.sma(close, 50)
buyCondition = ta.crossover(close, sma_val)

if (buyCondition)
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Buy: " + str.tostring(close), textcolor=color.white)

plot(sma_val, color=color.yellow)
```

[image]